# Can Management API be used to create a Google Analytics Account?

Tags: google-analytics

Suppose that a user has a Google account (say a Gmail account), but he does Not have a Google Analytics account.

Can we have a 3rd party application use the Management API (when the user is willing to authenticate it via OAuth2 using his Google account) to reach the stage of creating Tracking Code ?

I am asking this because, in https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/ , only 'list' is the method that is available for Accounts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't appear that you can create a fresh GA account from the Management API. You can, however, list, create, edit, and delete users from an existing GA account:

> User Permissions in the Management API allows you to list, create, edit, and delete users from your Google Analytics account. This is useful if you want to automate adding new users to Google Analytics, or removing a set of users.

[User Permissions - Developer Guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtUserPermissions)

[Add a Single User](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtUserPermissions#insert)

Comment: Yes even with google apps it can't be done, you can create a gmail account but not google analytics